# execute jar file using php script

Tags: java, php, executable-jar

I have to execute a jar file using php script. For that I have done like this ,

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('shell_exec')){ //to check server supports shell_exec
echo "Enabled";
} else {
echo "Disabled";
}$output= shell_exec("java -jar samplelib.jar abc");
echo 'output is:'$output; ?>
```

It shows shell_exec is 'enabled' But always gets $output  is null .  samplelib.jar file consists as below

```
 public class MainActivity  {
   public static String main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("Inside jar function");

           Log.i("","Inside jar function");

           if(args.length==0)
           {
                   return "args[] is NULL";
           }
           else
           {
           return args[0];
           }
       }
     }
```

Both 'Log.i' and 'System.out.println' is not displaying on console of browser .

Also tried with exec() ;

```
exec("java -jar samplelib.jar abc", $output);
```

It always return Array ( ) .

Comment: Why not do return false and echo something or something to make sure, the java program is executing